# RAID 5 configuration and future expansion

Tags: raid-5, expansion

I am building a PC to act as a file server among other things, and I was wondering whether it is a good idea to create 2 partitions on the RAID 5 array, one for OS one for data, or to have a separate disk for OS and use array for data.

Also, one day i may want to add another disk to the array, so would there be any issues if I had the OS partition on the RAID5 array when it came to resizing the data partition?